# Can I bind to full screen complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a Telerik RadEditor inside a RadWindow.
My goal is to have it so that when the user presses F11 the RadEditor will fill the entire screen.

Currently,
When I press F11 the radeditor goes fullscreen inside the RadWindow and then browser goes fullscreen.

I tried binding to the OnClientCommandExecuted property and maximizing the RadWindow there but this just results in a small maximized editor within a maximized radwindow. (If that makes any sense.)

Right now I see my only option as using a `setTimeout` but that can be unpredictable.

Is there a way of knowing when the browser has finished becoming fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the resize event to resize your Editor